# Multiple identical async pipe in Angular causing multiple http requests

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my angular app I'm using async pipe to render acomponent multiple times

```
<app-main-chart  [type]="type" [name]="Name" [values]="values$ | async" [objectifs]="dataObjectifs"></app-main-chart>
...
...
<app-main-chart  [type]="type" [name]="Name" [values]="values$ | async" [objectifs]="dataObjectifs"></app-main-chart>
```

The problem is that is causing multiple http request.

how can I use only one request ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Method 1

You can use [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) operator.

> Share source and replay specified number of emissions on subscription.

```js
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

values$ = source
  .pipe(
    shareReplay()
  );
```

---

### Method 2

You can subscribe in the controller and use that value in the template.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.values$.subscribe(values => this.values = values);
}
```

Then in the template:

```html
<app-main-chart [type]="type" 
                [name]="Name" 
                [values]="values" 
                [objectifs]="dataObjectifs">
</app-main-chart>
```

---

### Method 3

You can wrap it in `ngIf` block:

```html
<div *ngIf="values$ | async as values">
  <app-main-chart [type]="type" 
                  [name]="Name" 
                  [values]="values" 
                  [objectifs]="dataObjectifs">
  </app-main-chart>
  <app-main-chart [type]="type" 
                  [name]="Name" 
                  [values]="values" 
                  [objectifs]="dataObjectifs">
  </app-main-chart>
</div>
```